# Screenshots App Store: status bar or no status bar

Tags: iphone

I am about to submit my app to the App Store for review.

The app is running on iPhone, requires iOS 7 or later and it's optimised for iPhone 5,6 and 6 plus which means I have to submit screenshots for all these devices.

With the 6 and 6 plus sizes I am ok.

5.5in (iPhone 6 Plus):
1242 × 2208px portrait (with status bar)

4.7in (iPhone 6):
750 × 1334px portrait (with status bar)

What about the 4in? Do I crop the status bar and submit 640 × 1096px portrait (without status bar)
or do I leave it and submit
640 × 1136px portrait (full screen)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation you need to follow this.

[image]

[image]

[image]
Follow this this will help you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are running it on your simulator then press

> command+s

it will save your picture Don't need to crop any thing just submit original resolution picture on iTunes